# Can't add subcategory Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

When I try to add a subcategory they disappear after a page-refresh. I can add products to them but they do not show up in front and backend.

Any ideas?

I've already "cleared transients" and "recounted the terms" in Woocommerce settings. Both with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this code to file functions.php of your Wordpress theme:

```
//Добавляем Подкатегории В Постоянные Ссылки В Woocommerce
remove_filter( 'post_type_link', 'woocommerce_product_cat_filter_post_link', 10, 2 ); // для версии woocommerce ниже 2.0 
remove_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wc_product_post_type_link', 10, 2 ); // для версии woocommerce >= 2
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'woocommerce_subcategory_permalink', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_subcategory_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {

    // Прекращаем работу, если запись не является товаром
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' )
        return $permalink;

    // Прекращаем работу, если тег перезаписи местоположения не находится в генерируемой ссылке
    if ( false === strpos( $permalink, '%product_cat%' ) )
        return $permalink;

    // Получаем пользовательскую таксономию, используемую этой записью
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%product_cat%', _x('product', 'slug', 'woocommerce'), $permalink );
    } else {
        $first_term = array_shift( $terms );

        // Получаем иерархическую product_category
        $parents = woo_get_term_parents( $first_term->term_id, 'product_cat' );

        $permalink = str_replace( '%product_cat%/', $parents, $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woo_get_term_parents' ) ) {
    function woo_get_term_parents( $id, $taxonomy ) {
        $chain = '';
        $parent = &get_term( $id, $taxonomy );
        if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) )
            return $parent;

        $name = $parent->slug;

        if ( $parent->parent && ( $parent->parent != $parent->term_id )  ) {
            $chain .= woo_get_term_parents( $parent->parent, $taxonomy);
        }

        $chain .= $name."/";
        return $chain;
    } // End woo_get_term_parents()
}
```